# How to show specific items of an array in Laravel

Tags: laravel

I am using Laravel.i want to show only the Name in my View Part. But facing problem.

```
function index() {
    $data=array(
        ['id'=>'1','Name'=>'Debasais','sirname'=>'Acharya'],
        ['id'=>'2','Name'=>'prashant','sirname'=>'Mohaptra'],
        ['id'=>'3','Name'=>'Silu','sirname'=>'Mohaptra']);

    return view("welcome")->withdata($data);
}
```

Comment: I don't understand your question. Could you please edit it to provide more detail. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To show just the name in your view, just loop through `$data` and select only name.

```
@foreach($data as $names)
 {{$names['Name']}}
@endforeach
```

I am pretty sure you are already looping through `$data` just make sure to output the name only